# Bitronix with springboot and kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, bitronix

I want to know if bitronix have the same support as atomikos with logcloud (But it is paid) where it stores the transaction logs into centralised table so it can work with kubernetes and can do transaction recovery. If anyone know more about this please share

As per my knowledge bitronix stores the transaction logs on local system so it may not work when multiple instances of microservice are deployed using kubernetes